# How does MaxItemCount from FeedOption and RetrievedDocumentCount from QueryMetric works in Cosmos DB and why both never match?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am currently facing query performance issue with Cosmos DB and I am quite sure I have followed most of the performance tips from Microsoft page but still query takes > 1 second.

Connection policy

```
private static readonly ConnectionPolicy ConnectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
    {
        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
        ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
        RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
        MaxConnectionLimit = 1000,
        RetryOptions = new RetryOptions
        {
            MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
            MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60
        }
    };
```

Document Client

```
this.Client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(config.DocumentDBURI), config.DocumentDBKey, ConnectionPolicy);
```

Document Query

```
FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions
                {
                    MaxItemCount = config.getSearchLimit,//// which is 100
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey),
                    RequestContinuation = responseContinuation
                };

                var documentQuery = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<SearchByAttributesResult>(
                    this.TenantCollectionUri,
                    querySpec,
                    options).AsDocumentQuery();
```

Query 1

```
SELECT p.Doc.id, p.Doc.Name, p.Doc.isOrganization,p.Doc.organizationLegalName, p.Doc.isFactoryAutoUpdate,p.Doc.StartDate, p.Doc.EndDate, p.Doc.InactiveReasonCode,p.Doc.Specialty.specialty AllSpecialty, Address from p JOIN Address IN p.Doc.Address.address  WHERE  (p.Doc.EndDate = null or (p.Doc.StartDate <= @STARTDATE and p.Doc.EndDate >= @ENDDATE)) and  CONTAINS(p.Doc.Name, @PROVIDERNAME) and  Address.alpha2Code= @ALPHA2CODE
```

Query 2

```
    SELECT p.Doc.id, p.Doc.Name, p.Doc.isOrganization,p.Doc.organizationLegalName, p.Doc.isFactoryAutoUpdate,p.Doc.StartDate, p.Doc.EndDate, p.Doc.InactiveReasonCode,p.Doc.Specialty.specialty AllSpecialty, Address from p JOIN Address IN p.Doc.Address.address  WHERE  (p.Doc.EndDate = null or (p.Doc.StartDate <= @STARTDATE and p.Doc.EndDate >= @ENDDATE)) and  STARTSWITH(Address.postalCode, @POSTALCODE) and  Address.alpha2Code= @ALPHA2CODE
```

above query changes based on user search condition

I have only 900 documents in my collection but still query takes > 1 seconds always.

trying to understand few points here

- Though I set MaxItemCount to 100 why I am seeing RetrievedDocumentCount from QueryMetrics as 900?
- use of CONTAINS/STARTSWITH causing this performance issue?

What's wrong I am doing here and how can i improve this query performance into sub-seconds ( <.5s)

Answer (score 2):

First things first, MaxItemCount doesn't mean that you will get the top 100 documents.

It means that every iteration of `ExecuteNextAsync` will return up to 100 documents at a time, but up to everything that matches this query.

If you want to limit your results to the top 100 then, in LINQ use the `.Take(100)` method before you use `AsDocumentQuery` or in SQL use the `TOP` keyword.

In terms of performance, it's bad for three reasons.

- Checking for records between range of dates
- You are using the `CONTAINS/STARTSWITH` function.
- You are joining

At this point, if changing the schema isn't an option, I would recommend reading more about [Indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies) and optimising it based on the querying requirements of your application.

Comment: I agree with you that MaxItemCount would return up to 100 documents but I am not sure why ReterievedDocumentCount shows different no ( mostly total no of documents in a collection). due my query is it?

Comment: Yeah this query retrieved this many documents in total. You can read more about that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics